# In plain English what is prefix, postfix, infix in Swift?

Tags: swift, operators

I keep reading them along where I see the keyword `left`  & `right` but still confused of why I see them all together...

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how it relates to swift specifically, but "infix", "prefix", and "postfix" are different ways of parsing operators.

- Infix: `(x) + (y)`
- Prefix: `+ (x) (y)`
- Postfix: `(x) (y) +`

Where x and y are themselves expressions. It can seem more natural to use infix, but it can be easier for machines to use prefix or postfix. Adding machines, for example, use postfix.

Reading about it in Swift, it sounds like in Swift you can define your own operators, and it's up to you whether to make them infix, prefix, or postfix. Additionally, it sounds like in Swift prefix and postfix operators must be unary. So really, it's just about determining which side of the operand a unary operator will appear on:

- Infix (binary): `(x) + (y)`
- Prefix (unary): `+(x)`
- Postfix (unary): `(x)+`